# How can I rename my Kindle books?

Tags: kindle, ebook-management

This is a bit pedantic, but I don't like how certain books appear on my Kindle. The names are great when you're searching for products on Amazon, but they're unwieldy and annoying when navigating your device.

Consider the following:

The book simply called:

> "IT"

but the title on my device is:

> "It: Film tie-in edition of Stephen King's IT"

Pretty annoying.

Or others:

> "4.50 from Paddington"

Appears as:

> "4.50 from Paddington (Miss Marple) (Miss Marple Series Book 8)"

And...

> "Praise of Folly"

Appears as:

> "Praise of Folly [with Biographical Introduction]"

There are countless such examples in my collection (this is just the top five from my Amazon account at the moment).

How can I rename these book to be their ACTUAL titles?

Here's a screenshot, showing what I mean:

[image]

Comment: https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=274174 doesn't seem possible :(